# Facebook PHP - posting error to timeline but not to page

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post to a Facebook account (with permissions) using the PHP
API. I am giving our users two options - posting to the Feed, and posting
to a specific facebook page. I am getting an error in the first case, but
not in the second case. In the code below:

$access_token  is the access token I got back from linking to my app. It's of type
"User", and has the following permissions:

```
 email
 pages_show_list
 business_management
 pages_read_engagement
 pages_manage_metadata
 pages_read_user_content
 pages_manage_ads
 pages_manage_posts
 pages_manage_engagement
 public_profile
```

Where $page_token is, well, a "Page" type token, with the same set of permissions.

When I post to the page, it works fine. But when I try to post to the timeline, I get
the error:

```
Graph Error 200 : [Timeline]: [(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being 
installed in the group, and either publish_to_groups permission with user token, 
or both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; 
If posting to a page, requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts 
as an admin with sufficient administrative permission]
```

I'm not trying to post to a group, I'm posting to an account's timeline. And, per the
access token debugger, I have the permissions requested anyway. What's going on?

My code is below:

```
$linkData = [
                'link'            => $link_to_post,
                'appsecret_proof' => $app_secret_proof
            ];

if ( POSTING TO TIMELINE )
{
    $token   = $access_token;
    $post_to = "/me/feed";
}
else
{
    $page_id = $page_id;
    $token   = $page_token;
    $post_to = "/$page_id/feed";
}

// THIS THROWS THE EXCEPTION:
$response = $this->fb->post($post_to, $linkData,  $token);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not post to a personal timeline via API any more, that was removed ages ago already. (With introduction of API v2.4, if I remember correctly.)

You can only use the Share or the Feed dialog, to offer the user a way to *actively* share / make a post themselves, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web

Comment: Thanks, I guess I missed that.